# Where to set Vim colouring when logged into a remote machine

Tags: vim, colors

I do most of my development on a desktop, using Eclipse, but occasionally I have to log into the production machine to look at or edit files. Usually I use vi - which is an alias to Vim 7.2.

The colour scheme that Vim uses is terrible, and in some cases quite difficult to read.

Where do I set this (the colour scheme)? Is it my user profile on the remote machine? Or on my terminal on the local desktop?

Comment: Do you think the color scheme is bad on the remote machine or generally, i.e., also on your local machine? - You could turn highlighting off by typing `:syntax off` or by configuring `syntax off` in your `$HOME/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out which colorschemes are installed (and try them out) via `:colorscheme <Tab>` (or `<C-D>`).

If you've found a nice one, just `:edit ~/.vimrc` and put the corresponding command in there.

Some colorschemes look better if you have a high-color terminal. You can find out the number of available colors via `:set t_Co?`; you can also try increasing the number (to `256`), though it's better to configure a correct value for `$TERM` and have Vim figure the number out by itself.